# Dropzone does not click and does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, dropzone

My Dropzone does not click and does not work.

I already looked in other topics, but I didn't get the correct answer to my problem.

Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=dropzone_css) }}"/>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=dropzone_js) }}"></script>

<div class="text-center">
    <div id="dropzone" class="m-3" style="max-width: 720px; display:none;">
        <form action="#" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="demo-upload">
          <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <button type="button" class="dz-button">
                <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                    <font style="vertical-align: inherit; font-size: large;">test, test, test,test, test</font>
                </font>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo_envia_zona m-4" style="display:none">
    </div>
</div>
```

what should I do?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to open devtools in the browser and check for errors you need to debug.

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary to make a dropzone instance in jquery:

```
$("#demo-upload").dropzone();
```

details at: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically

Comment: No, it is not necessarily make an instance programmatically. By default the dropzone option "autodiscover" is set to true. Then all page elements with the css class "dropzone" are converted to dropzone instance. See the COFIGURATION SECTION on the dropzone webpage. I believe your rendering engine does not render correctly or the dropzone files aren't there where they are expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear, why you set css property **display:none** of your dropzone div element:

```
<div id="dropzone" class="m-3" style="max-width: 720px; display:none;">
```

I used your code and it worked for me without any problems:
[Your Dropzone on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1X6H.png)

The only changes I made to set display:block property of the div element and
binding the Dropzone JS and CSS files locally.

I believe your problem is, that Dropzone files are not loaded correctly.
Please open the Developer Tools windows of your browser and check if there are
some error on the "console" tab.

Comment: i find out this erro on the console:[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
window.XMLHttpRequest.open
jquery.min.js:2 [Violation] 'load' handler took 238ms
jquery.min.js:2 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 1292ms

Comment: That is not an error what you got on the console. It's just a deprecation warning about synchronous Ajax requests. Synchronous ajax calls block your JavaScript runtime. If an synchronous Ajax request take too long time the user can not interact with the user interface within this time.



1. Another question are you sure that css property "display;none" for your wrapper DIV with id="dropzone" is correct? I would remove this css property first. 


2.Then please check if your LINK and SCRIPT tags are rendered correctly so that dropzone.css and dropzone.js files are binded.